# Important component that we should have them to use in the android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android studio 1.3 and when I open the `SDK Manager` I see many components for each `API` in that. For the `API23`, for the `API22`, for the `API21` and etc.
 The components like the `platforms23` and etc or `Android SDK Tools23` or for the lower `APIs` or the `Android SDK Build Tools` and etc ......

Really if we want to use the `IDE` like android studio 1.3 and creating a project with `Minimum API` equal to the `9` What is needed to do this? When I see the `SDK Manager` window,I see many components in that to install, I want know the important components for creating a project in `IDE` like android studio 1.3.

Please say me the their name in here. Because I use android studio 1.3 and I have many components in the `sdk` folders. But still I do not know that which folders are important for creating a project in android studio.